# Cannot run custom unit-test in INet (OmNET++)

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

## EDIT

The original question complicates things, actually the problem is much simpler.

I try to simply run existing unit tests without adding anything. In the unit test `inet/tests/unit` folder I run:

```
./runtest
```

and get this:

```
andreatino@andreatino-virtual-machine:~/Git/inet/tests/unit$ ./runtest 
opp_test: extracting files from *.test files into work...

Creating Makefile in /home/andreatino/Git/inet/tests/unit/work...
Makefile created, running "make depend" to add dependencies...
Creating dependencies...
intervaltree/test.cc
In file included from /home/andreatino/Downloads/omnetpp-5.0/include/platdep/sockets.h:2:0,
                 from ../../../src/inet/common/precompiled.h:19,
                 from ../../../src/inet/common/INETDefs.h:22,
                 from ../../../src/inet/common/IntervalTree.h:42,
                 from intervaltree/test.cc:4:
/home/andreatino/Downloads/omnetpp-5.0/include/omnetpp/platdep/sockets.h:33:3: error: #error "#include <platdep/sockets.h> must precede <omnetpp.h> (and <platdep/timeutil.h> if present)"
 # error "#include <platdep/sockets.h> must precede <omnetpp.h> (and <platdep/timeutil.h> if present)"
   ^
Makefile:122: recipe for target 'out/gcc-debug//intervaltree/test.o' failed
make: *** [out/gcc-debug//intervaltree/test.o] Error 1
```

What is going on?

**Attention** You can avoid reading the original question actually. Unless you are curios about some getting more info on the issue.

## Original question

I am trying to run a custom test in the [INet Framework](https://github.com/inet-framework/inet), I am adding a custom test for a component I am writing. The files are part of [this commit](https://github.com/andry-tino/inet/commit/e43c502f404e60d401db292633119376df6578cd).

I am adding a test in: `inet/tests/unit`, please see the commit for the file structure.

#### Test files

The test file:

```
%description:
Test MacUtils in Ieee80211ac:
- Length of MU bundles is correctly computed.

%includes:
#include "ieee80211ac/MacUtilsTest.h"

%global:

using namespace ::inet::tcp::test::ieee80211ac;

%activity:
MacUtilsTest test = MacUtilsTest();

test.testMaxLengthReturned();

EV << ".\n";

%contains: stdout
l=7
.
```

And the included header:

```
#ifndef __INET_IEEE80211AC_MACUTILSTEST_H
#define __INET_IEEE80211AC_MACUTILSTEST_H

#include "inet/linklayer/ieee80211/mac/IMacParameters.h"
#include "inet/linklayer/ieee80211/mac/IRateSelection.h"
#include "inet/linklayer/ieee80211/mac/AccessCategory.h"
#include "inet/linklayer/ieee80211/mac/IRateControl.h"
#include "inet/linklayer/ieee80211/mac/Ieee80211Frame_m.h"

using namespace inet::ieee80211ac;

namespace inet {

namespace ieee80211ac {
class MacUtils;
class Ieee80211acMUBundleFrame;
}

namespace test {
namespace ieee80211ac {

/**
 * Tests focusing on utils on bundle messages.
 */
class MacUtilsTest
{
    protected:
        class DummyMacParameters : public inet::ieee80211::IMacParameters {
            public:
                virtual const MACAddress& getAddress() const override {}
                virtual bool isEdcaEnabled() const override {return false;}
                virtual simtime_t getSlotTime() const override {return 0;}
                virtual simtime_t getSifsTime() const override {return 0;}
                virtual simtime_t getAifsTime(inet::ieee80211::AccessCategory ac) const override {return 0;}
                virtual simtime_t getEifsTime(inet::ieee80211::AccessCategory ac) const override {return 0;}
                virtual simtime_t getPifsTime() const override {return 0;}
                virtual simtime_t getRifsTime() const override {return 0;}
                virtual int getCwMin(inet::ieee80211::AccessCategory ac) const override {return 0;}
                virtual int getCwMax(inet::ieee80211::AccessCategory ac) const override {return 0;}
                virtual int getCwMulticast(inet::ieee80211::AccessCategory ac) const override {return 0;}
                virtual simtime_t getTxopLimit(inet::ieee80211::AccessCategory ac) const override {return 0;}
                virtual int getShortRetryLimit() const override {return 0;}
                virtual int getLongRetryLimit() const override {return 0;}
                virtual int getRtsThreshold() const override {return 0;}
                virtual simtime_t getPhyRxStartDelay() const override {return 0;}
                virtual bool getUseFullAckTimeout() const override {return false;}
        };

        class DummyRateSelection : public inet::ieee80211::IRateSelection {
            public:
                virtual void setRateControl(inet::ieee80211::IRateControl *rateControl) override {}
                virtual const IIeee80211Mode *getSlowestMandatoryMode() override {return nullptr;}
                virtual const IIeee80211Mode *getModeForUnicastDataOrMgmtFrame(
                        inet::ieee80211::Ieee80211DataOrMgmtFrame *frame) override {return nullptr;}
                virtual const IIeee80211Mode *getModeForMulticastDataOrMgmtFrame(
                        inet::ieee80211::Ieee80211DataOrMgmtFrame *frame) override {return nullptr;}
                virtual const IIeee80211Mode *getModeForControlFrame(
                        inet::ieee80211::Ieee80211Frame *controlFrame) override {return nullptr;}
                virtual const IIeee80211Mode *getResponseControlFrameMode() override {return nullptr;}
        };

    protected:
        DummyMacParameters *macParameters = nullptr;
        DummyRateSelection *rateSelection = nullptr;
        MacUtils *utils = nullptr;
        Ieee80211acMUBundleFrame *bundleFrame = nullptr;

    protected:
        virtual void initialize();

    public:
        MacUtilsTest();
        virtual ~MacUtilsTest();

    public:
        void testMaxLengthReturned();
};

} // namespace ieee80211ac
} // namespace test
} // namespace inet

#endif
```

And implementation:

```
#include "MacUtilsTest.h"
#include "inet/linklayer/ieee80211ac/mac/MacUtils.h"
#include "inet/linklayer/ieee80211/mac/MacUtils.h"
#include "inet/linklayer/ieee80211ac/mac/Ieee80211acFrame_m.h"

using namespace inet::ieee80211ac;

namespace inet {
namespace test {
namespace ieee80211ac {

MacUtilsTest::MacUtilsTest()
{
    this->initialize();
}

MacUtilsTest::~MacUtilsTest()
{
    delete this->macParameters;
    delete this->rateSelection;
    delete this->utils;

    for (unsigned int i = 0, l = this->bundleFrame->getSingleFramesArraySize(); i < l; i++)
        delete this->bundleFrame->getSingleFrames(i);
    delete this->bundleFrame;
}

void MacUtilsTest::initialize()
{
    this->macParameters = new MacUtilsTest::DummyMacParameters();
    this->rateSelection = new MacUtilsTest::DummyRateSelection();
    this->utils = new inet::ieee80211ac::MacUtils(this->macParameters, this->rateSelection);

    this->bundleFrame = new Ieee80211acMUBundleFrame("MU Bundle");

    Ieee80211acDataFrame* data1 = new Ieee80211acDataFrame("Data-1");
    data1->setByteLength(3);
    Ieee80211acDataFrame* data2 = new Ieee80211acDataFrame("Data-2");
    data2->setByteLength(6);
    Ieee80211acDataFrame* data3 = new Ieee80211acDataFrame("Data-3");
    data3->setByteLength(7);

    this->bundleFrame->setSingleFramesArraySize(3);
    this->bundleFrame->setSingleFrames(0, *data1);
    this->bundleFrame->setSingleFrames(0, *data2);
    this->bundleFrame->setSingleFrames(0, *data3);
}

void MacUtilsTest::testMaxLengthReturned()
{
    int64_t length = this->utils->getMUBundleByteLength(this->bundleFrame);
    EV << "l=" << length << endl;
}

} // namespace ieee80211ac
} // namespace test
} // namespace inet
```

I'm adding them here just for the sake of this question, but in the commit I linked you can get more info about where these files are.

#### Cannot compile

I try then running `./runtest` in the `unit` folder and get this:

```
andreatino@andreatino-virtual-machine:~/Git/inet/tests/unit$ ./runtest 
opp_test: extracting files from *.test files into work...

Creating Makefile in /home/andreatino/Git/inet/tests/unit/work...
Makefile created, running "make depend" to add dependencies...
Creating dependencies...
IEEE80211ac_MacUtils_MUBundleLength/test.cc
In file included from /home/andreatino/Downloads/omnetpp-5.0/include/platdep/sockets.h:2:0,
                 from ../../../src/inet/common/precompiled.h:19,
                 from ../../../src/inet/common/INETDefs.h:22,
                 from ../../../src/inet/linklayer/ieee80211/mac/AccessCategory.h:23,
                 from ../../../src/inet/linklayer/ieee80211/mac/IMacParameters.h:23,
                 from ./lib/ieee80211ac/MacUtilsTest.h:4,
                 from IEEE80211ac_MacUtils_MUBundleLength/test.cc:4:
/home/andreatino/Downloads/omnetpp-5.0/include/omnetpp/platdep/sockets.h:33:3: error: #error "#include <platdep/sockets.h> must precede <omnetpp.h> (and <platdep/timeutil.h> if present)"
 # error "#include <platdep/sockets.h> must precede <omnetpp.h> (and <platdep/timeutil.h> if present)"
   ^
In file included from IEEE80211ac_MacUtils_MUBundleLength/test.cc:4:0:
./lib/ieee80211ac/MacUtilsTest.h:10:23: error: ‘ieee80211ac’ is not a namespace-name
 using namespace inet::ieee80211ac;
                       ^
./lib/ieee80211ac/MacUtilsTest.h:10:34: error: expected namespace-name before ‘;’ token
 using namespace inet::ieee80211ac;
                                  ^
./lib/ieee80211ac/MacUtilsTest.h:65:9: error: ‘MacUtils’ does not name a type
         MacUtils *utils = nullptr;
         ^
./lib/ieee80211ac/MacUtilsTest.h:66:9: error: ‘Ieee80211acMUBundleFrame’ does not name a type
         Ieee80211acMUBundleFrame *bundleFrame = nullptr;
         ^
./lib/ieee80211ac/MacUtilsTest.h: In member function ‘virtual const inet::MACAddress& inet::test::ieee80211ac::MacUtilsTest::DummyMacParameters::getAddress() const’:
./lib/ieee80211ac/MacUtilsTest.h:30:72: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
                 virtual const MACAddress& getAddress() const override {}
                                                                        ^
IEEE80211ac_MacUtils_MUBundleLength/test.cc: At global scope:
IEEE80211ac_MacUtils_MUBundleLength/test.cc:13:25: error: ‘inet::tcp’ has not been declared
 using namespace ::inet::tcp::test::ieee80211ac;
                         ^
IEEE80211ac_MacUtils_MUBundleLength/test.cc:13:36: error: ‘ieee80211ac’ is not a namespace-name
 using namespace ::inet::tcp::test::ieee80211ac;
                                    ^
IEEE80211ac_MacUtils_MUBundleLength/test.cc:13:47: error: expected namespace-name before ‘;’ token
 using namespace ::inet::tcp::test::ieee80211ac;
                                               ^
IEEE80211ac_MacUtils_MUBundleLength/test.cc: In member function ‘virtual void IEEE80211ac_MacUtils_MUBundleLength::Test::activity()’:
IEEE80211ac_MacUtils_MUBundleLength/test.cc:28:1: error: ‘MacUtilsTest’ was not declared in this scope
 MacUtilsTest test = MacUtilsTest();
 ^
IEEE80211ac_MacUtils_MUBundleLength/test.cc:28:1: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from IEEE80211ac_MacUtils_MUBundleLength/test.cc:4:0:
./lib/ieee80211ac/MacUtilsTest.h:25:7: note:   ‘inet::test::ieee80211ac::MacUtilsTest’
 class MacUtilsTest
       ^
IEEE80211ac_MacUtils_MUBundleLength/test.cc:30:1: error: ‘test’ was not declared in this scope
 test.testMaxLengthReturned();
 ^
IEEE80211ac_MacUtils_MUBundleLength/test.cc:30:1: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from IEEE80211ac_MacUtils_MUBundleLength/test.cc:4:0:
./lib/ieee80211ac/MacUtilsTest.h:19:16: note:   ‘inet::test’
 namespace test {
                ^
Makefile:123: recipe for target 'out/gcc-debug//IEEE80211ac_MacUtils_MUBundleLength/test.o' failed
make: *** [out/gcc-debug//IEEE80211ac_MacUtils_MUBundleLength/test.o] Error 1
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong... Or even what is going on here...

Answer (score 1):

Starting from OMNeT++ 4.2 `<platdep/sockets.h>` MUST precede `<omnetpp.h>` as mentionend in the changelog:

https://svn-itec.uni-klu.ac.at/trac2/dash/browser/trunk/omnet_simulation/omnet/doc/API-changes.txt?rev=140#L57

Within inet they ensured the right order by adapting the `src/makefrag` in the following commit:

https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/commit/d9abbd1b4df5b9efcfb7a7f58e8f2223f4a91a33

So, you have to add a `makefrag` file in the same folder as your `Makefile` with the following code:

```
PRECOMPILED_HEADER=<path-to-inet>/src/inet/common/precompiled.h
CFLAGS += -include $(PRECOMPILED_HEADER)
```

Consider replacing `<path-to-inet>` by your paths e.g. `../../`

**UPDATE:** The changelog for OMNeT++ 5.1 Preview 3 emphasis, that the issue is resolved:

```
Ordering of 'platdep/sockets.h' and 'omnetpp.h' is no longer important. It is recommended to include 'omnetpp.h' first.
```

Comment: Wow, some stuff I need to do for sure. Thanks for the info, I am gonna try them and let you know!

Comment: So I get your suggestion, however if I add this `makefrag` in the root folder containing my makefile, this is going to impact everything when I compile. Shouldn't I do this only in the `test` folder? Because INET has already taken care in `src` with a `makefrag` there. Am I reasoning right?

Comment: So even thought the `tests` folder does not have a `Makefile`? So to recap, I think that creating a `makefrag` in `inet` is not correct, so I will be adding it in `tests`. Is it right? Sorry for asking so much, just wanna make sure I am not doing wrong

Comment: It does not work if I place `makefrag` under `tests` :(

Comment: It does not work even if I place the file in the root: `inet` :(

Comment: I have solved it editing `runtest` in `tests/unit` by adding `cp makefrag work/` before invoke to `opp_makemake`...

Comment: But the question is: can I achieve this without changing the framework code? It seems unreasonable to me that they did not think about it...